# how to add glue to a custom section header

Tags: macros, sectioning, glue

I have generated a customized section heading style as follows:

```
\newcommand\ueber[1]{\vspace{0.2cm}\normalsize\itshape #1 \vspace{0.05cm}\normalfont}
```

So far, it works fine. However, I don't know how I can add "glue", so that the heading doesn't ever get separated from the subsequent paragraph when it appears at the end of a page.
How can I add glue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yu should take a look at the `titlesec` documentation, in particular, you might be inerested in the `nobottomtitles` option  (§ 3.3 Spacing related tools).

Comment: glue is tex word for space so you have added that already you want a _penalty_  so `#1\par\nopagebreak\vspace{0.05cm}\normalfont` although using a latex heading would be better.

Answer (score 1):

glue is tex word for space so you have added that already you want a *penalty*  so `#1\par\nopagebreak\vspace{0.05cm}\normalfont` although using a latex heading would be better.

```
\newcommand\ueber[1]{%
  \par\vspace{0.2cm}%
  \normalsize\normalfont\itshape #1%
  \par\nopagebreak \vspace{0.05cm}%
  \normalfont}
```